# How to add a value to a context with callbacks following Fluent Builder pattern

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, builder, fluent

I'm using Fluent Builder with callbacks to configure a context on the fly.

Currently, I have a `PlaneContext` class with a list of `passengers` which I want to populate by using the method `AddPassenger` like:

```
var builder = new PlaneBuilder<PlaneContext>();

builder.AddPlane(plane => plane.Name = "Boeng") 
    .AddPassenger(passenger => passenger.Name = "Robert")
    .AddPassenger(passenger => passenger.Name = "Johnny");
```

As shown above, I've created a `PlaneBuilder` class to chain methods like these. The first method `AddPlane` works fine, but the chained methods `AddPassenger` does not work as expected. My lack of understanding in delegates as `Action<T>` and `Func<T, TResult>` is highly the issue.

This is what I have tried, but I get cannot implicitly convert `string` to `Passenger`:

```
public PlaneBuilder<T> AddPassenger(Func<Passenger, Passenger> callback)
{
    var passenger = callback(new Passenger());
    _planeContext.Passengers.Add(passenger);
    return this;
}
```

Currently, this is how the `PlaneBuilder` class looks like:

```
class PlaneBuilder<T>
{

    private PlaneContext _planeContext = new PlaneContext();

    public PlaneBuilder<T> AddPlane(Action<PlaneContext> callback)
    {
        callback(_planeContext);
        return this;
    }

    public PlaneBuilder<T> AddPassenger(Func<Passenger, Passenger> callback)
    {
        // Goal is to create a passenger
        // Add it to the passengers list in PlaneContext
        var passenger = callback(new Passenger());
        _planeContext.Passengers.Add(passenger);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's the `PlaneContext` class:

```
class PlaneContext
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public List<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
}
```

In short, how can I add passenger to `PlaneContext` using callbacks?

Comment: A very similar question was asked recently here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021513/using-fluent-interface-with-builder-pattern Following that advice you could just add a separate Passenger builder

Comment: Thanks @SimonKatanski! I manage to solve the problem, I also realize I had another problem where I forgot to initialize the list which gave me error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I'll post a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

The is a solution to my problem as described above:

First, the list must be initialized in `PlaneContext` class like:

```
public List<Passenger> Passengers = new List<Passenger>();
```

Secondly, in order to add a passenger to `Passengers` list: create a new instance of `Passenger` class, pass it as an argument to the `callback` method, and then add it to the `passengers` list like:

```
public PlaneBuilder<T> AddPassenger(Action<Passenger> callback)
{
    var passenger = new Passenger();
    callback(passenger);
    _planeContext.Passengers.Add(passenger);
    return this;
}
```